Visual Studio intellisense highlighting the wrong item
Let's say I want to do Debug.Writeline(...), and System.Diagnostics isn't imported. I usually type out "Debug", hit Ctrl+Space, and intellisense would bring up a list of options. The correct option is the first one, which would automatically add the import for me, but the highlighted option is ALWAYS the second one which is a namespace:

Half the time, I'm completing something that doesn't match one of my namespaces, and it highlights the right suggestion. Half the time, it highlights a namespace that's only MARGINALLY similar to the name of an unimported class, and I end up hitting tab and having to undo it, which is exceedingly annoying. Why does it always prioritize a namespace? I don't recall seeing this behavior just a few years ago. How do I disable this?

Based on my test, you can try to use third-party extensions like ReShareper to override Visual Studio native IntelliSense. It will highlight the correct item.

That namespace is selected because it's the first one alphabetically that can be reached from your using namespace statements as they are. All the others require additional using namespace statements, specifically with the namespace listed to the right of each entry.
There's an additional sorting algorithm that's AI-driven and is enabled when you enable Intellicode or Github Copilot, and their recommendations are inserted to the top of the list with a big star to the right of the identifier. You obviously don't have it enabled, since there are no stars in your list.

As @Blindy said, "That namespace is selected because it's the first one alphabetically". I guess it could be by-design. If you don't want to use the Visual Studio native intellisense, here is a workaround: you can install extensions like ReSharper to override VS IntelliSense.
Test result

When i type out "Debug", ReSharper intellisense brings up a list of options.The correct option is the first one and the highlighted option is the first one too.
You can configure settings from Extensions->ReSharper->Tools

Besides you can also submit a feature request that will allow you to directly interact with the appropriate product group, and make it more convenient for the product group to collect and categorize your suggestions.
Hope it can help you.
